# Random CGPointMake?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cgpoint

How can I make a random CGPointMake, say i created an outlet of a uiimage and called it image, image.center = CGPointMake (//random, //random) everytime second (NSTimer)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `arc4random()` in stdlib.h. This utilizes a much more superior algorithm than `rand()`. Look up this function in the man pages. You will then want to mod the generated values by the maximum coordinates that you want for both axes.

```
int x = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.width;
int y = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.height;

image.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

Comment: i am getting an error saying something about not allowing frame in QTWO

Comment: Is this code in your controller? If so, put view between self and frame (self.view.frame).

Comment: i have another error saying invalid operands to binary expression (float and CGFloat)

Comment: Cast the width/height to an int.

Comment: How can i do that, what does CAST mean?

Answer (score 1):

you can use rand() in stdlib.h

something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

srand ( time(NULL) );
int max = 400         // or whatever
int myRandomNumber1 = rand() % max
int myRandomNumber2 = rand() % max

image.center = CGPointMake(myRandomNumber1, myRandomNumber2);
```

Comment: stdlib.h is the C standard library

Comment: if i use this code the image moves far and then SO CLOSE to the place it was before for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Use `arc4random()`, you don't even need to seed it.

```
image.center = CGPointMake(arc4random() % yourView.frame.size.width, arc4random() % yourView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: if i do the view then it says something about assigning float to CGFloat * i dunno